# write files/cookies with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2, writefile

How should I go about with writing files that should not be accessible to the public? First how can I write to file outside of the CI root folder? Second to be able to write file, I need to set the file permission to 777, which then would become accessible to the public. How should I approach this?

Comment: First of all, you have to get permissions to set thw owner of your server files. Take a look here: http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver and the use fopen, fwrite and fclose normaly.

Answer (score 0):

The [CI File Helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html) will "help" you do this:

```
$this->load->helper('file');
write_file('./path/to/file.php', $data);
```

The path to the file can be a relative path or an absolute path, so you can write this file anywhere on the system (even above the CI root folder - as long as you have permissions to write to the directory.

For example:

```
// CI Root folder is at /var/www/my_ci_project
// Directory to write to is at /var/www/tmp_files
$this->load->helper('file');
write_file('/var/www/tmp_files/file.php', $data);
```

As for the permissions, you just need the file to be group writable by the webserver user:

```
// Everything for owner, read and execute for owner's group
chmod("/var/www/tmp_files/file.php", 0770);
```